# getting total amount in my cashiering system

Tags: java, arrays, methods

i have a cashiering system and here's my codes:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class FinalProject {

    private static final int totalsundae = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int totaldrinks = 0, totalfries = 0, totalburger = 0, totalsundae = 0;

        FinalProject m = new FinalProject();
        m.Cashiering();

    }

    public void Cashiering() {
        String menu[] = {"Customer's Name", "Menu", "Pay", "View Order list", "Exit"};
        String choice = "";
        char ch;

        do {
            choice = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please select your order", "menu", 1, null, menu, menu[0]);
            ch = choice.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            switch (ch) {

                case 'c':
                    customer();

                    break;

                case 'm':
                    menu2();
                    break;
                case 'p':
                    getTotal();

                    break;
                case 'v':
                    orderList();
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    System.exit(0);

            }
        } while (!choice.equals("Close"));
    }

    public void customer() {

        String name = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog("WELCOME !!!!!  \n\nPLEASE ENTER YOUR NAME: ");
        try {
            PrintWriter printW = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("cash.txt", true));
            printW.println("Customer's Name " + "\n" + name);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Name successfully stored  \n\n You can Order Now ");
            printW.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public int burger() {
        int burger = 0, quantity = 0, totalburger = 0;
        int choice;
        String burgnm = "";

        String menu = "\nBURGER: \n1.Regular Burger 45 \n2.Burger with cheese---->55 \n3.Burger with egg and cheese----50 \n4.Burger with ham---->60 \n5.Burger with ham and cheese---->70 ";

        choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please select: " + menu));

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                burger += 45;
                burgnm = "Regular Burger - ";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
                break;
            case 2:
                burger += 55;
                burgnm = "Burger with cheese - ";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
                break;
            case 3:
                burger += 50;
                burgnm = "Burger with egg and  cheese - ";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
                break;
            case 4:
                burger += 60;
                burgnm = "Burger with ham - ";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
                break;
            case 5:
                burger += 70;
                burgnm = "Burger with ham and cheese - ";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
        }

        if (quantity < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
        } else {
            totalburger = quantity * burger;
            burgnm = burgnm + totalburger + "\n";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total = " + burgnm);

            try {
                PrintWriter printW = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("cash.txt", true));
                if (choice == 1) {
                    printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + burgnm);
                } else if (choice == 2)
                    printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + burgnm);
                else if (choice == 3)
                    printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + burgnm);

                else if (choice == 4)
                    printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + burgnm);
                else if (choice == 5)
                    printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + burgnm);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record successfully stored ");
                printW.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return totalburger;
    }

    public int Spaghetti() {
        int choice, quantity = 0, totalspag = 0, spaghetti = 0;
        String spagnm = null;

        String menu = "\nSPAGHETTI: \n1.Regular spaghetti---->60 \n2.Large Spaghetti---->70";
        choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please select: " + menu));

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                spaghetti += 60;
                spagnm = "Regular Spaghetti - ";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
                break;
            case 2:
                spaghetti += 70;
                spagnm = "Large Spaghetti - ";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
        }

        if (quantity < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
        } else {
            totalspag = quantity * spaghetti;
            spagnm = spagnm + totalspag + "\n";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total = " + spagnm);

            try {
                PrintWriter printW = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("cash.txt", true));
                if (choice == 1) {
                    printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + spagnm);
                } else if (choice == 2)
                    printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + spagnm);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record successfully stored ");
                printW.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return totalspag;
    }

    public int Fries() {
        int choice, fries = 0, quantity = 0, totalfries = 0;
        String friesnm = "";
        String menu = "\nFRIES: \n1.Regular Fries ----> 35\n2.Medium Fries ----> 45 \n3.LargeFries ----> 55";
        choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please select: " + menu));

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                fries += 35;
                friesnm = "Regular Fries - ";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
                break;
            case 2:
                fries += 45;
                friesnm = "Medium Fries - ";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
                break;
            case 3:
                fries += 55;
                friesnm = "Large Fries - ";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
        }

        if (quantity < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
        } else {
            totalfries = quantity * fries;
            friesnm = friesnm + totalfries + "\n";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total = " + friesnm);

            try {
                PrintWriter printW = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("cash.txt", true));
                if (choice == 1) {
                    printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + friesnm);
                } else if (choice == 2)
                    printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + friesnm);
                else if (choice == 3)
                    printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + friesnm);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record successfully stored ");
                printW.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return totalfries;
    }

    public int Sundae() {
        int choice, quantity = 0, sundae = 0, totalsun = 0;
        String sundaenm = "";
        String menu = "\nSUNDAE: \n1.Choco sundae ----> 28 \n2.Caramel sundae ----> 28 \n3.Strawberry sundae ----> 28";
        choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please select: " + menu));
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                sundae += 28;
                sundaenm = " Choco Sundae -";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
                break;
            case 2:
                sundae += 28;
                sundaenm = " Caramel Sundae ";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
                break;
            case 3:
                sundae += 28;
                sundaenm = " Strawberry Sundae - ";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
        }

        if (quantity < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
        } else {
            totalsun = quantity * sundae;
            sundaenm = sundaenm + totalsun + "\n";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total = " + sundaenm);

            try {
                PrintWriter printW = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("cash.txt", true));
                if (choice == 1) {
                    printW.println("Costumer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + sundaenm);
                } else if (choice == 2)
                    printW.println("Costumer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + sundaenm);
                else if (choice == 3)
                    printW.println("Costumer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + sundaenm);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record successfully stored ");
                printW.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return totalsun;
    }

    public int Drinks() {
        int choice, quantity = 0, drinks = 0, totaldrinks = 0;
        String drinksnm = "";
        String menu = "\nDRINKS: \n1.Reg. Coke ----> 25 \n2.Large Coke ----> 35 \n3.Reg.Sprite ----> 28 \n4.Large Sprite ----> 38";
        choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please select: " + menu));

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                drinks += 25;
                drinksnm = "Regular Coke - ";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
                break;
            case 2:
                drinks += 35;
                drinksnm = "Large Coke - ";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
                break;
            case 3:
                drinks += 28;
                drinksnm = "Regular Sprite - ";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
                break;
            case 4:
                drinksnm = "Large Sprite - ";
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));

                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
        }

        if (quantity < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
        } else {
            totaldrinks = quantity * drinks;
            drinksnm = drinksnm + totaldrinks + "\n";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total = " + drinksnm);

            try {
                PrintWriter printW = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("cash.txt", true));
                if (choice == 1) {
                    printW.println("Costumer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + drinksnm);
                } else if (choice == 2)
                    printW.println("Costumer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + drinksnm);
                else if (choice == 3)
                    printW.println("Costumer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + drinksnm);

                else if (choice == 4)
                    printW.println("Costumer's Order " + "\n" + quantity + drinksnm);


                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record successfully stored ");
                printW.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return totaldrinks;
    }

    public void orderList() {
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("cash.txt"));
            String all = "\nWELCOME !!!!   \nCASHIERING SYSTEM\n";
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                all = all + in.nextLine() + "\n";

            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea(all));
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void getTotal() {

    }

    public void menu2() {
        String menu[] = {"Burger", "Spaghetti", "Fries", "Ice Sundae", "Drinks", "Exit"};
        String choice = "";
        char ch;
        int yesorno = 0;

        do {
            choice = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please select your order", "menu", 1, null, menu, menu[0]);
            ch = choice.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            switch (ch) {

                case 'b':
                    burger();
                    yesorno = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you still have any order?? \n 1.Yes \n2.No"));
                    if (yesorno == 1) {
                        menu2();

                    } else {
                        Cashiering();
                    }

                    break;
                case 's':
                    Spaghetti();
                    yesorno = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you still have any order?? \n 1.Yes \n2.No"));
                    if (yesorno == 1) {
                        menu2();

                    } else {
                        Cashiering();
                    }
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    Fries();
                    yesorno = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you still have any order?? \n 1.Yes \n2.No"));
                    if (yesorno == 1) {
                        menu2();

                    } else {
                        Cashiering();
                    }

                    break;
                case 'i':
                    Sundae();
                    yesorno = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you still have any order?? \n 1.Yes \n2.No"));
                    if (yesorno == 1) {
                        menu2();

                    } else {
                        Cashiering();
                    }
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    Drinks();
                    yesorno = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you still have any order?? \n 1.Yes \n2.No"));
                    if (yesorno == 1) {
                        menu2();

                    } else {
                        Cashiering();
                    }

                    break;
                case 'e':
                    break;

            }

        } while (!choice.equals("Close"));
    }
}
```

my problem here is the total. how can i get the total of the customer's order by using a method? i'm really a beginner in java so i hope you can give some simple codes. thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a totalOrder variable to store the total for that session.

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;

  public class FinalProject {

private int totalOrder;
private static final int totalsundae = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int totaldrinks = 0, totalfries = 0, totalburger = 0, totalsundae = 0;

    FinalProject m = new FinalProject();
    m.Cashiering();

}

public void Cashiering() {
    String menu[] = { "Customer's Name", "Menu", "Pay", "View Order list",
            "Exit" };
    String choice = "";
    char ch;

    do {
        choice = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Please select your order", "menu", 1, null, menu, menu[0]);
        ch = choice.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        switch (ch) {

        case 'c':
            customer();

            break;

        case 'm':
            menu2();
            break;
        case 'p':
            getTotal();

            break;
        case 'v':
            orderList();
            break;
        case 'e':
            System.exit(0);

        }
    } while (!choice.equals("Close"));
}

public void customer() {

    String name = (String) JOptionPane
            .showInputDialog("WELCOME !!!!!  \n\nPLEASE ENTER YOUR NAME: ");
    try {
        PrintWriter printW = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("cash.txt",
                true));
        printW.println("Customer's Name " + "\n" + name);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Your Name successfully stored  \n\n You can Order Now ");
        printW.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public int burger() {
    int burger = 0, quantity = 0, totalburger = 0;
    int choice;
    String burgnm = "";

    String menu = "\nBURGER: \n1.Regular Burger 45 \n2.Burger with cheese---->55 \n3.Burger with egg and cheese----50 \n4.Burger with ham---->60 \n5.Burger with ham and cheese---->70 ";

    choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please select: "
            + menu));

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        burger += 45;
        burgnm = "Regular Burger - ";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
        break;
    case 2:
        burger += 55;
        burgnm = "Burger with cheese - ";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
        break;
    case 3:
        burger += 50;
        burgnm = "Burger with egg and  cheese - ";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
        break;
    case 4:
        burger += 60;
        burgnm = "Burger with ham - ";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
        break;
    case 5:
        burger += 70;
        burgnm = "Burger with ham and cheese - ";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
        break;
    default:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
    }

    if (quantity < 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
    } else {
        totalburger = quantity * burger;
        burgnm = burgnm + totalburger + "\n";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total = " + burgnm);

        try {
            PrintWriter printW = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("cash.txt",
                    true));
            if (choice == 1) {
                printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + burgnm);
            } else if (choice == 2)
                printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + burgnm);
            else if (choice == 3)
                printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + burgnm);

            else if (choice == 4)
                printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + burgnm);
            else if (choice == 5)
                printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + burgnm);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Record successfully stored ");
            printW.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    totalOrder = totalOrder + totalburger;
    return totalburger;
}

public int Spaghetti() {
    int choice, quantity = 0, totalspag = 0, spaghetti = 0;
    String spagnm = null;

    String menu = "\nSPAGHETTI: \n1.Regular spaghetti---->60 \n2.Large Spaghetti---->70";
    choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please select: "
            + menu));

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        spaghetti += 60;
        spagnm = "Regular Spaghetti - ";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
        break;
    case 2:
        spaghetti += 70;
        spagnm = "Large Spaghetti - ";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
        break;
    default:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
    }

    if (quantity < 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
    } else {
        totalspag = quantity * spaghetti;
        spagnm = spagnm + totalspag + "\n";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total = " + spagnm);

        try {
            PrintWriter printW = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("cash.txt",
                    true));
            if (choice == 1) {
                printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + spagnm);
            } else if (choice == 2)
                printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + spagnm);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Record successfully stored ");
            printW.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    totalOrder = totalOrder + totalspag;
    return totalspag;
}

public int Fries() {
    int choice, fries = 0, quantity = 0, totalfries = 0;
    String friesnm = "";
    String menu = "\nFRIES: \n1.Regular Fries ----> 35\n2.Medium Fries ----> 45 \n3.LargeFries ----> 55";
    choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please select: "
            + menu));

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        fries += 35;
        friesnm = "Regular Fries - ";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
        break;
    case 2:
        fries += 45;
        friesnm = "Medium Fries - ";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
        break;
    case 3:
        fries += 55;
        friesnm = "Large Fries - ";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
        break;
    default:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
    }

    if (quantity < 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
    } else {
        totalfries = quantity * fries;
        friesnm = friesnm + totalfries + "\n";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total = " + friesnm);

        try {
            PrintWriter printW = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("cash.txt",
                    true));
            if (choice == 1) {
                printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + friesnm);
            } else if (choice == 2)
                printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + friesnm);
            else if (choice == 3)
                printW.println("Customer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + friesnm);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Record successfully stored ");
            printW.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    totalOrder = totalOrder + totalfries;
    return totalfries;
}

public int Sundae() {
    int choice, quantity = 0, sundae = 0, totalsun = 0;
    String sundaenm = "";
    String menu = "\nSUNDAE: \n1.Choco sundae ----> 28 \n2.Caramel sundae ----> 28 \n3.Strawberry sundae ----> 28";
    choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please select: "
            + menu));
    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        sundae += 28;
        sundaenm = " Choco Sundae -";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
        break;
    case 2:
        sundae += 28;
        sundaenm = " Caramel Sundae ";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
        break;
    case 3:
        sundae += 28;
        sundaenm = " Strawberry Sundae - ";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
        break;
    default:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
    }

    if (quantity < 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
    } else {
        totalsun = quantity * sundae;
        sundaenm = sundaenm + totalsun + "\n";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total = " + sundaenm);

        try {
            PrintWriter printW = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("cash.txt",
                    true));
            if (choice == 1) {
                printW.println("Costumer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + sundaenm);
            } else if (choice == 2)
                printW.println("Costumer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + sundaenm);
            else if (choice == 3)
                printW.println("Costumer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + sundaenm);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Record successfully stored ");
            printW.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    totalOrder = totalOrder + totalsun;
    return totalsun;
}

public int Drinks() {
    int choice, quantity = 0, drinks = 0, totaldrinks = 0;
    String drinksnm = "";
    String menu = "\nDRINKS: \n1.Reg. Coke ----> 25 \n2.Large Coke ----> 35 \n3.Reg.Sprite ----> 28 \n4.Large Sprite ----> 38";
    choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please select: "
            + menu));

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        drinks += 25;
        drinksnm = "Regular Coke - ";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
        break;
    case 2:
        drinks += 35;
        drinksnm = "Large Coke - ";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
        break;
    case 3:
        drinks += 28;
        drinksnm = "Regular Sprite - ";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));
        break;
    case 4:
        drinksnm = "Large Sprite - ";
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("How many do you want??? "));

        break;
    default:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
    }

    if (quantity < 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID");
    } else {
        totaldrinks = quantity * drinks;
        drinksnm = drinksnm + totaldrinks + "\n";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total = " + drinksnm);

        try {
            PrintWriter printW = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("cash.txt",
                    true));
            if (choice == 1) {
                printW.println("Costumer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + drinksnm);
            } else if (choice == 2)
                printW.println("Costumer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + drinksnm);
            else if (choice == 3)
                printW.println("Costumer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + drinksnm);

            else if (choice == 4)
                printW.println("Costumer's Order " + "\n" + quantity
                        + drinksnm);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Record successfully stored ");
            printW.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    totalOrder = totalOrder + totaldrinks;
    return totaldrinks;
}

public void orderList() {
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("cash.txt"));
        String all = "\nWELCOME !!!!   \nCASHIERING SYSTEM\n";
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            all = all + in.nextLine() + "\n";

        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea(all));
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public void getTotal() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Order Total\n"+ totalOrder + "");

}

public void menu2() {
    String menu[] = { "Burger", "Spaghetti", "Fries", "Ice Sundae",
            "Drinks", "Exit" };
    String choice = "";
    char ch;
    int yesorno = 0;

    do {
        choice = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Please select your order", "menu", 1, null, menu, menu[0]);
        ch = choice.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        switch (ch) {

        case 'b':
            burger();
            yesorno = Integer
                    .parseInt(JOptionPane
                            .showInputDialog("Do you still have any order?? \n 1.Yes \n2.No"));
            if (yesorno == 1) {
                menu2();

            } else {
                Cashiering();
            }

            break;
        case 's':
            Spaghetti();
            yesorno = Integer
                    .parseInt(JOptionPane
                            .showInputDialog("Do you still have any order?? \n 1.Yes \n2.No"));
            if (yesorno == 1) {
                menu2();

            } else {
                Cashiering();
            }
            break;
        case 'f':
            Fries();
            yesorno = Integer
                    .parseInt(JOptionPane
                            .showInputDialog("Do you still have any order?? \n 1.Yes \n2.No"));
            if (yesorno == 1) {
                menu2();

            } else {
                Cashiering();
            }

            break;
        case 'i':
            Sundae();
            yesorno = Integer
                    .parseInt(JOptionPane
                            .showInputDialog("Do you still have any order?? \n 1.Yes \n2.No"));
            if (yesorno == 1) {
                menu2();

            } else {
                Cashiering();
            }
            break;
        case 'd':
            Drinks();
            yesorno = Integer
                    .parseInt(JOptionPane
                            .showInputDialog("Do you still have any order?? \n 1.Yes \n2.No"));
            if (yesorno == 1) {
                menu2();

            } else {
                Cashiering();
            }

            break;
        case 'e':
            break;

        }

    } while (!choice.equals("Close"));
  }
 }
```

Comment: i've already tried this. but when i call the method getTotal(), the method where they order will appear again. what i really want is when i call the getTotal() method, the methods where they order will not appear again.

Comment: Let me know if that worked for you. It should return the total sum of the order in a MessageDialog. You can change it to display however you need.  :-)